# Rest Api passing null values to sql database

Tags: c#, rest

I have an Object which has a property statusDate of type DateTime. This property is a nullable type with implementation as:

```
public DateTime? statusDate {get;set;}
```

I am using Rest Api to insert data into the database. I get error 400 Bad Request. After some Googling I have realized that because the value is null my Rest Api url is throwing the error. How do I pass null values to Rest Api

Example: http://localhost:62733/api/Claims/InsertAsync/username=Zainalds&statusDate=null

```
        public static async Task<long> PostAsyncLong<T>(Uri uri, T postObject)
        {
           var httpContent = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(postObject), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
           var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(uri, httpContent, _cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

           return await GetResult<long>(response);
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps `http://localhost:62733/api/Claims/InsertAsync/username=Zainalds` ? Though I would expect you to be using a request body rather than passing values through as a query string parameter.

Comment: @John i am using swagger also. Just to give an example, I have added the request Url.

Comment: Is the username being bound to your object? Have you tried using browser dev tools or a proxy like Fiddler to examine what you are sending?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is pretty straight forward make sure all submodules are updated to use latest POCO classes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon what type of API request you accessing [GET] or [POST]

### GET REQUEST

> Request accessing you need to handle on code level eg.

- *API URL - api/testController/InsertAsync?username=Zainalds&statusDate=null*

  ```
     [HttpGet]
     public string InsertAsync(string username, DateTime? statusDate)
     {            
        return "value";
     }
  ```

---

### POST REQUEST

> Request accessing you don't need to assign value for statusDate then default set to null eg.

#### Request Model

```
public class InsertAsyncRequest
{
     public string username { get; set; }
     public DateTime? statusDate { get; set; }
}
```

#### In API Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 public string InsertAsync(InsertAsyncRequest _req)
 {    
     return "value";
 }
```